# Make a character optional only on last occurrence of capture group

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to use regex in my C++ application to test if strings match a common array-type format. The string should match a list of numbers separated by commas, surrounded by any amount of whitespace characters and encapsulated by curly braces. So,

```
 {1, 2, 3}`, 
 {12.234,2313.4231, 
 {+1.232, -2313.32,    12}
```

should all be matched as correct. My current regex string is this (spaces added for clarity):

```
\\{ ( \\s*?[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]?,\\s*? )+ \\}
```

The problem with this string is that the comma is *required* after each number in order to be considered a valid string. That is, the string `{12, 12, 12,}` works, but the string `{12, 12, 12}` does not match because of the missing last comma. I could make the comma optional by including a `?` after it, but that would make the string `{12 12 12}` valid, which I want to avoid.

How should I go about making the comma character only optional on the *last* occurrence in the string?

Here's a code snippet to illustrate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex test("\\{(\\s*?[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]?,\\s*?)+\\}");
    std::string input;
    while(1){
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if(input == "exit")
            break;
        if(std::regex_match(input, test))
            std::cout << "string matches" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "string does not match" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::regex test("\\{\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*(?:,\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)*\\s*\\}");`

Comment: It appears you want one number, then  any number of (, number)   As long as you don't want all numbers in in a group, which the speciification doesn't require,  I'd done the same. Just make this an answer, @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, works like a charm. If you'd like to submit that as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the three strings you mention at the top are valid (`{1, 2, 3}`, `{12.234,2313.4231,}` and `{+1.232, -2313.32,    12}`) you may use two approaches: an alternation with a positive lookahead that would check if there is a `}` at the end (`(?:,\\s*|(?=\\}$))`)

```
std::regex test("\\{(?:\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*(?:,\\s*|(?=\\}$)))+\\}");
```

or adding an optional comma `,?` before the last `}`:

```
std::regex test("\\{\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*(?:,\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)*\\s*,?\\}");
```

See [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/EpBRTb/2) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/EpBRTb/3).

If `{1, 2, 3,}` is not valid the best way is to unrol the repeated group:

```
std::regex test("\\{\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*(?:,\\s*[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)*\\s*\\}");
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EpBRTb/4).